# VS2012 "Generating Code" slow with large hardcoded arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, visual-studio-2012

We have a tool that generates a class in a header file which is generated with hardcoded arrays. That autogenerated is inherited by a real implementation which uses the autogenerated values.

Autogenerated example:

```
class MyTestAutoGen
{
    std::vector<int> m_my_parameter1;
    std::vector<int> m_my_parameter2;
    ...

public:
    MyTestAutoGen()    
    {
        SetDefaultValueFor_my_parameter1();
        SetDefaultValueFor_my_parameter2();
        ...
    }

    void SetDefaultValueFor_my_parameter1()
    {
        int tmp[] = {121,221,333,411,225,556,227,.......};
        m_my_parameter1.assign(tmp, tmp + 65025);
    }

    void SetDefaultValueFor_my_parameter2()
    {
        int tmp[] = {333,444,333,987,327,16728,227,.......};
        m_my_parameter2.assign(tmp, tmp + 65025);
    }

    ...
 };
```

Compiling this takes a lot of time and in the Output windows of VS I can see that it hangs on the "Generating Code" phase of the compilation, but it will finish the compile after about 15-30min unless the compiler crashes with a stack overflow.

I have tried to enable the "Multiprocessing Compilation" and the "Parallel Code Generation" flags but it did not show any improvements. Disabling the "Whole Program Optimization" is not an option as after the application initialization it should perform as optimized as possible.

My workaround to this issue was to modify the autogenerated template to save the values in encoded binary string so that maybe the data will be stored in the TEXT area instead of the STATIC area of the library/executable. So now the autogenerated code looks like (the stringed hex values are just for show):

```
class MyTestAutoGen
{
    std::vector<int> m_my_parameter1;
    std::vector<int> m_my_parameter2;
    ...

public:
    MyTestAutoGen()    
    {
        SetDefaultValueFor_my_parameter1();
        SetDefaultValueFor_my_parameter2();
        ...
    }

    void SetDefaultValueFor_my_parameter1()
    {
        std::string codedDefaultValue = "\x079\0\0\0.......";
        std::stringstream str(codedDefaultValue);

        int tmp;
        for (int i = 0; i < codedDefaultValue.length() / sizeof(int); i++)
        {
            str.read((char*) &tmp, sizeof(int));
            m_my_parameter1.push_back(tmp);
        }
    }

    void SetDefaultValueFor_my_parameter2()
    {
        std::string codedDefaultValue = "\x04d\x001.......";
        std::stringstream str(codedDefaultValue);

        int tmp;
        for (int i = 0; i < codedDefaultValue.length() / sizeof(int); i++)
        {
            str.read((char*) &tmp, sizeof(int));
            m_my_parameter2.push_back(tmp);
        }
    }

    ...
 };
```

This compiles fast but is not easily readable (this file should not be edited manually and is not causally looked at).

Is there a better way to do this without breaking it as cross-platform, without disabling optimizations and keeping it a header file?

Comment: Why can't you disable LTO? I think it's okay if developement executables are not as fast, in the development phase fast compilation is more important. You can still use LTO in the product build.

Comment: This autogen file is being used by other developers which need to test their "heavy" implementations on-the-run, so for them it is both development and production. Creating 2 build configurations (with and without) will be hassle for all parties involved.

Comment: Why does it have to be kept in the header file? Could you not auto-generate a CPP file with the `SetDefaultValueFor_my_parameter1` definitions in?

Comment: @TripeHound I do it in a single file to simplify the external integrations. I have tried extracting the code manually to a cpp file and add it to the project but it did not have any effect on the speed

Comment: "We have a tool that generates a class in a header file" You can instead use a tool that generates the object files directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your auto-generated numbers are meant to be constant. This is expressed by `static const`:

```
static const int tmp[] = {121,221,333,411,225,556,227,.......};
```

There is a vague rule that for "large" arrays, automatic storage (i.e. normal local variables) should not be used; use `static` instead (alternatively, use dynamic allocation, but this is not needed here). In addition, since your numbers will not be changed, use `const` too.

BTW it's pretty surprising that breaking this "rule" affects compilation time!

Comment: Can you explain why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

If you have to keep the workaround:  For more readability, you might want to extract the function which decodes the string.

```
void fill(std::vector<int>& dest, const std::string& src)
{
  std::stringstream str(src);
  const size_t size = src.length() / sizeof(int);
  int tmp;
  dest.clear();
  dest.reserve(size);
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
    str.read((char*) &tmp, sizeof(int));
    dest.push_back(tmp);
  }
}

void SetDefaultValueFor_my_parameter1()
{
  fill(m_my_parameter1, "\x079\0\0\0.......");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My hunch is that you're pushing a large array of unspecified size on the stack. Because stack buffer overflows are a particular safety concern. MSVC is careful with them. But there's no point in having that array on the stack.

Instead, do at global scope

```
const int count = 65025;
int param1_initializer[count] = {121,221,333,411,225,556,227, ... }
```

Note that you already hardcoded the array length, so it's strongly advisable to give the compiler a chance to check it. Furthermore, this makes it easier for the compiler to know how many initializers are expected, so the compiel time may also benefit.

[edit]
Since this isn't sufficient, and we know we're using MSVC, use `#pragma optimize` to turn off *all optimizations* of the array definitions. It's not like they can be optimized anyway.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have tried to modify the code generator to produce as you suggested but the long compilation time remained, even though it does take less then before.

Comment: I have wrapped all of the SetDefaulrValueFor functions implementations with the pragmas for on and off, but compilation is still dead slow (over 4 min and counting).